# Join two Tables Only on First Set of Values

Tags: mysql, join

```
Table 1 : Anamoly

    id Source
    1   dls
    2   aus
    3   dls
    4   aus
Table 2 : Logical_Mapping

Source Destination minValue
dls       hst         1
aus       hst         2
dls       buf         1
aus       buf         2

Expected Output
Anomaly-Mapping
id  Source Destination   minValue
1    dls    hst(or)buf      1
2    aus    hst(or)buf      2
3    dls    hst(or)buf      1
4    aus    hst(or)buf      2
```

The 'minValue' is dependent on the source and not the 'destination'.

The query I tried was :

```
select an.id,an.Source, (select l.Destination from logical_mapping as l where an.Source= l.Source limit 1) as Dest from anomaly;
```

The query seems to work fine. But I need 'minValue' also along with 'Destination'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT an.id, an.source, l.destination, l.minValue
FROM anamoly an
LEFT JOIN logical_mapping l ON l.source=an.source
```

Comment: I am sorry for not clearly explaining my output. I meant it to be like either 'hst' or 'buf'. Also I require all the rows in the first table even if did not have corresponding entry in second table.